# How to configure setup.py to distribute egg

Tags: java, python, netbeans, jython

First my goal is to share this the easiest way possible with non-computer geeks that already have Java JRE installed.

I’m using Netbeans with Python and Jython plugins. I started a **Python project** and wrote my code. I import standard JAVA packages and only one Java add-in

import gnu.io

import gnu.io.RXTXPort as RXTX
RXTX is added to JDK/JRE and JRE I assume this will be a dependency

The program runs fine from within Netbeans and now I want to make an egg.
The project SRC folder contains 29 .py  + 25 .class + 7 .jpg + 2 .XML files  and   __ INIT __.py

I right-click the project and use CLEAN and BUILD EGG
This puts a setup.py file in the source directory and creates a built and info folder.
I also issued the Jython command from within the project SRC folder            jython setup.py  bdist_egg

Both methods run to completion and produce the following

folder build
-------- subfolder bdist.java1.80_251 -- which is empty

folder dist
------- file JythonProject0.1-py2.7.egg -- contents = list of egg-info files

folder JythonProject.egg-info  with

------ file  dependency_links.txt      --  no content

------ file PKG-INFO                   --  summary of setup.py entries

------ file SOURCES.txt                --  setup.py + list of these files

------ file top_level.txt              --  no content

I’ve studied about the structure of the setup.py file but I’ll admit that without an example I’m left confused about the syntax of filling in the blanks.

**QUESTION: how do I add my source data to get a working egg?**

```
Setup.py =
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup 
name='JythonProject'
version='0.1'
packages=find_packages()   **supposed to find all .PY files ?**
                           **how to include CLASS files?**

# Declare your packages' dependencies here, for eg:
install_requires=[]        **my RXTX?  path/xx.JAR?**

# Fill in these to make your Egg ready for upload to
# PyPI
author='jwkel'
author_email='email@gmail.com'
#summary = 'Just another Python package for the cheese shop'
url=''  **none**
license='' **I understand this**
long_description='Long description of the package'
```

Comment: here what you looking for https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/main/setup.py and for packaging & testing https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/

Answer (score 0):

I needed move my setup.py file to the root directory (not in the same folder with the source files.) and things began to happen. From there warnings guided my actions. Here is my setup.py that gave me my first resultd. Now to study rst and MD so I can add a README file.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup (
       name='JythonProject',
       version='0.1',
       zip_safe=True,
       packages=find_packages(),
       # Declare your packages' dependencies here, for eg:
       install_requires=[],
       data_files=[('',['src/cars_pic.jpg','src/rfid_pic.jpg','src/readers_pic.jpg','src/polling_pic.jpg','src/mode_pic.jpg','src/locations_pic.jpg','src/engine_pic.jpg','src/RFIDconfig.xml','src/JMRIimportedData.xml'])],
       # Fill in these to make your Egg ready for upload to
       # PyPI
       author='James w Kelly',
       author_email='jwkelly49@gmail.com',

       #summary = 'Just another Python package for the cheese shop',
       url='',
       license='MIT',
       long_description='Long description of the package',

       # could also include long_description, download_url, classifiers, etc.

  
       )
```